# Importing a SSL certificate in window server 2016

Tags: windows-10, ssl, certificate, windows-server

According to the [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/hpcpack-2016-cluster) of Microsoft HPC pack for windows server 2016, I have run the following command to create a certificate. There is no problem with the command but the HPC pack requires the PFX file and asks me to browse/import the certificate. I don't know the PFX location!

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "www.fabrikam.com", "www.contoso.com" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"


   PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\My

Thumbprint                                Subject                                                                             
----------                                -------                                                                             
48B96D527ACCB90D34E5FC4F51784B4BB6DF9B3F  CN=www.fabrikam.com
```

Where should I look for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you ran placed the certificate in the LocalMachine\Personal store. To export it as a PFX file, follow these steps:

1. Right-click the Start button and click **Run**
2. Type **mmc** and hit Enter
3. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (or click **File** -> **Add/Remove Snap-in...**)
4. Select **Certificates** from the **Available snap-ins** and click **Add >**
5. Select **Computer account** and click Next, then Finish
6. Expand **Certificates (Local Computer)** -> **Personal** -> **Certificates**
7. Right-click your certificate in the pane on the right and select **All tasks** -> **Export...**
8. Follow the wizard to export your certificate to a PFX file (select **Yes, export the private key** to export it as PFX).